# Error parsing Xml

Tags: java

SAXParseException is occuring while iam trying to parse an xml unsing dom parser

here is the code using

```
public static getAlertsFromXML(InputStream strAlerts) {
                              DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource is = new InputSource(strAlerts);        
                is.setEncoding("UTF-8"); 
                Document doc =db.parse(is); 
}
```

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file is showing while running the code.

xml  is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<seloger result="1" url="http://wshp.seloger.com/getalerts.xml?printerid=3Gs8rsDHrclGqD1Hrr1p08dr2" version="1.0">
<!-- ID3x v4.60 (387) - X29 - 00.056.330 - base - 14/03/2012 09:56:09 - getalerts.xml -->
 -<listalerts> -<alert> <alertId>10049086</alertId> <description>locations d'appartements ou de maisons situées dans le 75, ayant une surface supérieure à 567 m², pour un loyer inférieur à 100 000 000 €/mois, triées par prix.</description> <creationDate>2011-10-13T11:16:00</creationDate> <queryString>cp=75&idqfix=1&idtt=1&idtypebien=1,2&px_loyerbtw=NAN%2f100000000&surfacebtw=567%2fNAN&tri=</queryString> </alert> -<alert> <alertId>9348308</alertId> <description>ventes situées à Caen (Calvados), à Cambes (Lot-et-Garonne), à Paris 1er, à Paris 2ème, à Paris 3ème, à Paris 4ème, à Paris 5ème, à Paris 6ème, à Paris 7ème, à Paris 8ème, à Paris 9ème, à Paris 10ème, à Paris 11ème, à Paris 12ème, à Paris 13ème, à Paris 14ème, à Paris 15ème, à Paris 16ème, à Paris 17ème, à Paris 18ème, à Paris 19ème ou à Paris 20ème, ayant une surface inférieure à 1 000 m², triées par prix.</description> <creationDate>2011-06-27T07:42:00</creationDate> <queryString>ci=140118,470047,750101,750102,750103,750104,750105,750106,750107,750108,750109,750110,750111,750112,750113,750114,750115,750116,750117,750118,750119,750120&fakeci=750056&idqfix=1&idtt=2&idtypebien=all&nb_chambres=all&nb_pieces=all&pxbtw=NaN%2fNaN&surfacebtw=NaN%2f1000&tri=d_dt_crea</queryString> </alert> -<alert> <alertId>9337215</alertId> <description>ventes situées à Paris 1er, à Paris 2ème, à Paris 3ème, à Paris 4ème, à Paris 5ème, à Paris 6ème, à Paris 7ème, à Paris 8ème, à Paris 9ème, à Paris 10ème, à Paris 11ème, à Paris 12ème, à Paris 13ème, à Paris 14ème, à Paris 15ème, à Paris 16ème, à Paris 17ème, à Paris 18ème, à Paris 19ème ou à Paris 20ème, ayant une surface inférieure à 1 000 m², pour un prix compris entre 50 et 1 000 €, triées par prix.</description> <creationDate>2011-06-24T13:40:00</creationDate> <queryString>ci=750101,750102,750103,750104,750105,750106,750107,750108,750109,750110,750111,750112,750113,750114,750115,750116,750117,750118,750119,750120&fakeci=750056&idqfix=1&idtt=2&idtypebien=all&nb_chambres=all&nb_pieces=all&pxbtw=50%2f1000&surfacebtw=NaN%2f1000&tri=d_dt_crea</queryString> </alert> </listalerts> </seloger>
```

Comment: Can you show us the XML you are trying to parse?

Comment: Yes Xml is valid...becoz the follwoing exception is occured while i change the function parameter strAlerts to INputStream.I need to pass the paramaetr as Inputstream only

Comment: if you are sure that your xml is valid, you must think twice that you flush() the stream

Comment: You have non-escaped ampersands (`&`) in `<queryString>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ampersand is a reserved character in XML; `<marker>Bob & Mary Johnson</marker>` is not valid XML. You must escape it as & or wrap it in order to hide it from your XML parser, e.g. `<marker><![CDATA[Bob & Mary Johnson]]></marker>`.

For more information refer [List of XML and HTML character entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Comment: Xml is valid...becoz the follwoing exception is occured while i change the function parameter strAlerts to INputStream.I need to pass the paramaetr as Inputstream only

Comment: You mean <queryString>cp=75&idqfix=1&idtt=1&idtypebien=1,2&px_loyerbtw=NAN%2f100000000&surfacebtw=567%2fNAN&tri=</queryString> is valid? You can validate this fragment from your code either using any xml tool (Notepad++ etc.) or online http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote. Please add reason for downvote as comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an & in an xml stream unless you escape it